# Laravel Eloquent cannot insert to database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm making an app that runs like google form using Laravel 5.7. Here is the form table that i already made:

[image: 1st page]
[image: 2nd page] 
I made an eloquent model so that each Name in Personal details table has one record that contains all these table and insert filled table into database after click submit button. The problem is, it didn't successfully inserted into database. I don't know what's the problem, here are my codes:

**PersonalDetails.php (eloquent model)**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PersonalDetails extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'personal_details';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

public function accomodation()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Accomodation');
}

public function course()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Course');
}

public function proposedStudy()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\ProposedStudy');
}

public function emergencyContact()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\EmergencyContact');
}

public function englishTestResult()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\EnglishTestResult');
}

public function homeInstitution()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\HomeInstitution');
}

public function insurance()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Insurance');
}
}
```

**FormController.php**

```
public function submit(Request $request) {

    $request->validate([
        // Personal Details
        'fullname' => 'required|string',
        'nationality' => 'required|string',
        'date_of_birth' => 'required|string',
        'passport_number' => 'required|string',
        'issuing_country' => 'required|string',
        'date_of_issue' => 'required|string',
        'date_of_expiry' => 'required|string',
        'blood_type' => 'required|string',
        'marital_status' => 'required|string',
        'address' => 'required|string',
        'city' => 'required|string',
        'postal_code' => 'required|numeric',
        'province' => 'required|string',
        'country' => 'required|string',
        'phone' => 'required|string',
        'mobile' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'address2' => 'nullable|text',
        'city2' => 'nullable|string',
        'postal_code2' => 'nullable|numeric',
        'province2' => 'nullable|string',
        'country2' => 'nullable|string',
        'phone2' => 'nullable|string',
        'contact_name' => 'required|string',

        // Home Institution
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'address' => 'required|string',
        'phone' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'website' => 'required|string',
        'faculty_dep' => 'required|string',
        'start_year' => 'required|string',
        'gpa' => 'required|string',

        // Proposed Study
        'semester' => 'required|in:Semester I (Aug-Jan),Semester II (Feb-Jun)',
        'academic_year' => 'required|string',
        'faculty' => 'required|string',
        'department' => 'required|string',
        'study_period' => 'required|string',
        'start_date' => 'required|string',
        'end_date' => 'required|string',
        // Course
        'course_title' => 'required|string',
        'credit' => 'required|string',

        // English Test Result
        'test' => 'required|string',
        'score' => 'required|numeric',
        'test_center' => 'required|string',  
        'date_tested' => 'required|string',

        // Insurance
        'insurance_name' => 'required|string',
        'validity' => 'required|string',
        'cover' => 'required|string',

        // Accomodation
        'accomodation_help' => 'required|in:YES,NO',
        'adress' => 'required|string',
        'contact_person' => 'required|string',

        // Contact of Emergency
        'fullname' => 'required|string',
        'relationship' => 'required|string',
        'address' => 'required|string',
        'phone' => 'required|string',
        'mobile' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|email',


    ]);

    PersonalDetails::create([
        'fullname' => $request->input('name'),
        'nationality' => $request->input('nationality'),
        'date_of_birth' => $request->input('dob'),
        'passport_number' => $request->input('passport'),
        'issuing_country' => $request->input('is_country'),
        'date_of_issue' => $request->input('doi'),
        'date_of_expiry' => $request->input('doe'),
        'blood_type' => $request->input('blood'),
        'marital_status' => $request->input('maritial'),
        'address' => $request->input('address'),
        'city' => $request->input('city'),
        'postal_code' => $request->input('postal'),
        'province' => $request->input('state'),
        'country' => $request->input('country'),
        'phone' => $request->input('phone'),
        'mobile' => $request->input('mobile'),
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'address2' => $request->input('address2'),
        'city2' => $request->input('city2'),
        'postal_code2' => $request->input('postal2'),
        'province2' => $request->input('state2'),
        'country2' => $request->input('country2'),
        'phone2' => $request->input('phone2'),
        'contact_name' => $request->input('contact_name'),
    ]);

    HomeInstitution::create([
        'name' =>  $request->input('institution'),
        'address' =>  $request->input('i_address'),
        'phone' =>  $request->input('i_phone'),
        'email' =>  $request->input('i_email'),
        'website' =>  $request->input('web'),
        'faculty_dep' =>  $request->input('faculty_dept'),
        'start_year' =>  $request->input('s_year'),
        'gpa' =>  $request->input('gpa'),
    ]);

    ProposedStudy::create([
        'semester' => $request->input('duration'),
        'academic_year' => $request->input('f_year') . '/' . $request->input('l_year'),
        'faculty' => $request->input('faculty'),
        'department' => $request->input('department'),
        'study_period' => $request->input('spesific_period'),
        'start_date' => $request->input('start_date'),
        'end_date' => $request->input('end_date'),
    ]);

    Course::create([
        'course_title' => $request->input('course_1'),
        'credit' => $request->input('credit_1'),
    ]);

    EnglishTestResult::create([
        'test' => $request->input('toefl'),
        'score' => $request->input('score_toefl'),
        'test_center' => $request->input('place_toefl'),     
        'date_tested' => $request->input('date_toefl'),
    ]);

    Insurance::create([
        'insurance_name' => $request->input('insurance'),
        'validity' => $request->input('valid_date'),
        'cover' => $request->input('cover'),
    ]);

    Accomodation::create([
        'accomodation_help' => $request->input('opt_acc'),
        'adress' => $request->input('adress_acc'),
        'contact_person' => $request->input('cp_acc'),
    ]);

    EmergencyContact::create([
        'fullname' => $request->input('emergency_name'),
        'relationship' => $request->input('relationship'),
        'address' => $request->input('address_emergency'),
        'phone' => $request->input('emergency_phone'),
        'mobile' => $request->input('emergency_mobile'),
        'email' => $request->input('emergency_email'),
    ]);

    // return back()-> with('success', 'Berhasil submit!');
}
```

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: No sir, it has no error message. I have no idea what's the problem

Comment: Can you check the browser console -> network tab for the response code (200 or 404 or 422). My guess some validation failing

Comment: I think you have mass-assignment problem. You can add fillable varibale in your model. You can check here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment and you should put all validation in a separate request file. I know it is not related to your problem but it will make your controller thin. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests 
Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I guess it could be validation failure. Just check all your ```Form Fields``` and ```fields under validation```.  There could mismatch in fields.

Comment: just try dd($request-all()) and see what error give you. I think it is the problem with validation

Comment: Already tried that, it returns assoc array normally with given value, no problem, but my db keeps empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after all these struggles to figured out the problem, i just realized that i put wrong name in validation rules. The name on the left side of validation rules is different with name in html so i reformed the name in html and validation rules.

The big deal is i didn't put any validation error message after submit so that it won't inserted into database. After i put some error message, all of the field returned error that says "The :attribute is required". Simply because the name in validation is different with the html name :D

Thank you guys for helped me to figured out the problem, i worked it out :))

Answer (score 0):

try with model path,if model folder is inside App then App\model;

```
eg:-
App\Insurance::create([
        'insurance_name' => $request->input('insurance'),
        'validity' => $request->input('valid_date'),
        'cover' => $request->input('cover'),
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

add `$fillalbe` in Model:

```
protected $fillable=['full_name','nationality','...']
```

you will need to specify `fillalbe` attribute on the model. read more at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: This is not necessary if a `$guarded` attribute is specified, which it is. `While $fillable serves as a "white list" of attributes that should be mass assignable, you may also choose to use $guarded. The $guarded property should contain an array of attributes that you do not want to be mass assignable. All other attributes not in the array will be mass assignable.`

Comment: Agreed with Jeremy, i think it won't be necessary if i already attach guarded array excluding the $guarded it will be the $fillable lists

Comment: try by insterting static value.

Comment: then try by adding `$fillable` and remove `$guarded`

Comment: what you get when you dump `request`

Comment: No validation error occure. When i used dd($request->all()) it returned assoc array with inputted value normally, but it cannot inserted into database.

Comment: I would for the time being comment out all validation.  Enter proper data and see if that works.  If it does you then know it's somewhere in the validation.  But I think I would personally move out all of the creates into there own specific models just for cleaner code.

Comment: It returned so much errors when i comment out all validation, like it didn't match with proper value in db @BradGoldsmith

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your table migration or model relation, then revision your form controller.

I am create example from your code and successfull insert into database.

**Personal Details Migration**

```
Schema::create('personal_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('fullname')->nullable();
        $table->string('nationality')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Home Institution Migration**

```
Schema::create('home_institution', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('personal_details_id')->unsigned()->primary();
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('address')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        #Foreign to Table Personal Details.
        $table->foreign('personal_details_id')->references('id')->on('personal_details')->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

**Personal Detail Model Relation**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PersonalDetails extends Model
{
protected $guarded = ['id'];


public function homeInstitution()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\HomeInstitution');
}

# Other your Relation

}
```

**Form Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\PersonalDetails;

class FormController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    return view('form.index');
}

public function submit(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        // Personal Details
        'fullname' => 'required|string',
        'nationality' => 'required|string',
        // Home Institution
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'address' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    $pd = PersonalDetails::create(
        ['fullname' => $request->get('fullname'), 'nationality' => $request->get('nationality')]
    );

    # Insert into HomeInstitution => base on Model Relation from PersonalDetails
    $pd->homeinstitution()->create(
        ['name' => $request->get('name'), 'address' => $request->get('address')]
    );

    # Insert into other youR relation
    /*$pd->example()->create(
        []
    );*/


    return dd('Successfull Insert');
}
}
```

Maybe its can help you.